# Which one is better for pre/post statistical analysis, "difference" or "ratio"?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I have confusion about a simple statistical analysis:
one dependent variable measured before and after intervention in two groups. and the classical question is comparing effects between tow groups.

consider this case: (the value of independent vaiable presneted as 1 D vector)

group 1: Pre=[200 150 100 180]  -> Post =[100 75 50 90]
group 2: Pre=[20 15 10 18]      -> Post =[10 7.5 5 9]

the ratio(Post/pre) of change for both groups is 50%, which means no significant effect. while difference (Post-Pre)  is significantly larger in the first group.

or maybe I should use Anova. what's your solution?
Could you please help me to understand this issue!

Answer (score -1):

It might clarify what is happening if we formalize it.

Suppose $Y_{it}$ is your outcome variable with $t\in\{0,1\}$ for pre and post, and $T_{it}\in\{0,1\}$ is the treatment indicator.
(In your example we have that $T_{it}=t$.)

The question is, what is the conditional distribution of $Y_{it}$?
If the conditional mean is $E(Y_{it}\mid T_{it})=\alpha+\beta T_{it}$, then you get $\beta$ by subtracting the pre mean from the post mean.
If on the other hand $E(Y_{it}\mid T_{it})=e^{\alpha+\beta T_{it}}$, you get $e^\beta$ as $E(Y_{it}\mid T_{it}=1)/E(Y_{it}\mid T_{it}=0)$ which is the ratio, and $\beta$ by taking the log.

In other words, if you think the effect of the treatment is multiplicative, use the ratio. If you think it is additive, use the difference in means.

Comment: Thank for your insight. I am not familiar with the conditional distribution. Could you please tell me how i can check which one fits  better to my data: additive or multiplicative?